# vim regex: Match with negation in middle of pattern

Tags: regex, vim

I am trying to learn regular expressions in vim and have gotten stuck on the following task:

I want to make a substitute which matches all of the following lines - and similar - except for the one containing `Look aXXhead`. With similar I mean just anything in between the `a` and the `head` except `XX`.

```
Look ahead
Look aYhead
Look aXhead 
Look aXXhead    
Look aXXXhead
```

In case it is relevant I had my highest hopes when trying

```
:%s/Look a\(XX\)\@!head/*\0
:%s/Look a\(.*\&\(XX\)\@!\)head/*\0
```

which only matches `Look ahead` due to the zero width of the `\(XX\)\@!` I pressume.

Tries like

```
:%s/Look a\(XX\)\@!.*head/*\0
```

misses the "triple X" line.

So, how is it done?

P.S. This is my first post on stack exchange so please help and correct me in case there is better ways or places for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about:

```
/\vLook a(XXhead)@!.*head
```

or without `very magic`:

```
/Look a\(XXhead\)\@!.*head
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with this pattern:

```
/\(Look aXXhead\)\@!\&Look a.*head/
```

It's made of tho parts:

- `\(Look aXXhead\)\@!`

  match at every position in the file BUT not at `/Look aXXhead/`
- `Look a.*head`

  match also `/Look aXXhead/`

The `\&` operator tells that each of these parts have to match *at the same pos*.

Comment: Works perfectly! (Went for Kent's suggestion as it seem a bit cleaner though.)